# AngularJS: I am not able to get the http.get's JSON data from parent state's controller

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui-router

I have a nested view like so:

```
.state('xyz',{
    url:'/xyz',
    templateUrl: 'tpl/xyz.html'
    controller : 'xyzCtrl'
})
.state('xyz.abc',{
    url:'/abc',
    templateUrl: 'tpl/abc.html'
})
```

and controller:

```
app.controller('xyzCtrl', ['$scope','$htpp', function($scope,$http){
    $scope.data = [];
    $http.get('../js/data.json').then(function(res){
    $scope.data = res.data;
    });
}]);
```

The problem is I get the value for data in xyz's view but I am not able to get it in abc's view. Normally the child inherits the parents scope data right?

Comment: you have typo where you inject `$http` to your controller, now I can see that you inject `$htpp` instead of `$http`.

Comment: yeah sorry, i didnt format that before posting.. but it doesnt solve my problem..

Answer (score 0):

> abstract - {boolean=} - An abstract state will never be directly
>   activated, but can provide inherited properties to its common children
>   states.

Try this make **abstract:true**

```
.state('app',{
    abstract: true,
    url: '/app',
})
.state('app.xyz',{
    url:'/xyz',
    templateUrl: 'tpl/xyz.html'
    controller : 'xyzCtrl'
})
.state('app.abc',{
    url:'/abc',
    templateUrl: 'tpl/abc.html'
})
```

Comment: It says cannot transition to abstract state.. After adding abstract : true, I am not able to access xyz from the rootscope..

Comment: @BalaAbhinav make an abstract state first then your state.

Comment: i did that. but the views of xyz itself is not getting rendered in the rootscope now.